# How to parse a PHP variable using a dynamic JS variable?

Tags: javascript, php

I have 5 PHP variables, `$menu1` to `$menu5`, that each evaluate to a keyword. I'm trying to populate these 5 PHP variables in JavaScript, and display them. The below code doesn't work. What is wrong with my processing of the PHP variables?

```
var menu_populator = "";
for (var x = 1; x <= count; x++) {
    menu_populator += '<li><a class="myclass" href="#link">' + '<?php echo $menu' + x + '?>' + '</a></li>';
}
$('#nav_menu').html(menu_populator);
```

Comment: where is this code block located? because PHP dosen't run in js files

Comment: it's within the script tag in a php file.

Comment: I can think of a few different ways you could have this work. Just curious to were `count` is defined....

Comment: count is already defined:  var count="<?= $total_menu ?>";

Comment: $menu1 to $menu5 are they in array?

Comment: So `$total_menu` is the same amount of `$menu` variables you want to use in this loop? If so you can create an array and won't need to use `count` you could loop through the array...

Comment: Right, i will try that. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on how you are getting the menu data server-side you can try both methods below. One is for set `$menu` variables but if you are getting data from a database or the `$menu` variable are created within a loop you might find the second method better.

> Method one- [*PasteBin*](http://pastebin.com/WNp3FWkR)

Echo your php variables into a javascript array.

```
var myarray=["<?php echo $menu1;?>","<?php echo $menu2;?>","<?php echo $menu3;?>","<?php echo $menu4;?>","<?php echo $menu5;?>"];
```

> Method Two- [*PasteBin*](http://pastebin.com/5fA8wScJ)

Create this array server-side, this will be better if you are creating the current `$menu` variable in a loop, with this you can just use `array_push()` to push the values into the array.

```
<?php 
// PHP Array
$menu = array('Home', 'Gallery', 'About');
// How to push new item into array
array_push($menu, 'Contact');
?>
```

Then just simply echo this array into your javascript `myarray` variable.

```
var myarray=<?php echo json_encode($menu);?>;
```

---

I have used the following javascript to test both methods and both seem to function just fine. I prefer the second method but I have decided to offer both as I don't know what your PHP looks like or how your `$menu` variables are being defined so this should cover both.

```
window.onload=function(){
for(var i=0; i<myarray.length; i++){
    var link= document.createElement('a');
    link.href="#";
    link.innerHTML=myarray[i];
    document.body.appendChild(link);
    document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));
}
}
```

If you have any questions about the source code above please leave a comment below and I will get back to you as soon as possible.

I hope this help. Happy coding!

Comment: Method 1 looks promising, let me see if it works. Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: @schenker Very welcome. If you have any problems with this, just let me know and I will see if I can be of any further assistance.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this would do the trick

```
<?php
$menu = "menu";
echo '

<script>
    var count = 10;
    var menu_populator="";
    for(var x=1;x<=count;x++) 
    {
        menu_populator += \'<li><a class="myclass" href="#link">'.$menu.' \'+x+\'</a></li>\';
    }
    $(\'#nav_menu\').html(menu_populator);
</script>

';
?>
```